# Placing canvas (chart.js line chart) inside an SVG using d3.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, chart.js

I first tried doing so with a  and that worked great.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></button>
```

However when I attempted to do the same with a canvas object, in this case a line chart generated by the chart.js library it did not work. I'm using d3.js to insert the chart into the svg. I also put a breakpoint into my angularjs chart.js directive (I'm using chart.js via the directive) and I noticed that the directive is not invoked at all.

The foreignObject with the chart.js canvas is being inserted into the html, just no rendering.

```html
<foreignObject x="5" y="5">
  <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true" series="series" click="onClick"></canvas>
</foreignObject>
```

Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Comment: Not sure that I follow, could you put your code in a fiddle and provide a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the generated HTML

You need to set a height and width on the foreignObject

```
  d3.select("svg")
     .append("foreignObject")
         .attr("width", 480)
         .attr("height", 500)
```

and append the canvas to a body element under the foreignObject

```
  ...
  .append("xhtml:body")
      .html('<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true"></canvas>');
```

Here is a working snippet (check with Chrome)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]);
app.controller("chartController", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    $scope.data = [
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];
  }
])

d3.select("svg")
  .append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", 480)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .html('<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/master/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="chartController">
    <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time out to play with this. I shall give this a go when I get the chance today. I actually managed to get this to work without doing it the d3 way. So I just put it in plain html etc. <svg><foreignObject><canvas> and I did indeed have the problem where the height and width need to be pre-defined. Another issue I had was the mouse x and mouse y was off. So when I was hovering over the points they were not aligned to what was being rendered and for that reason to avoid having to mess about with scaling/positioning I decided to do them separately and instead hide/show.

Comment: Strange. I don't seem to have any problems with the hovering (in Chrome) and the hit detection seems to be balanced (it comes up when I'm at the same distance whether I come in from the right or the left).

Comment: False alaram, seems like Stackoverflows  Run Code Snippet was the issue, it works properly through a manual html file loaded into Chrome and the hit detection is spot on. Thanks :)